# Issue with CSS Parallax

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I'm having some issues with my parallax code. I'm trying to get that seamless look when you scroll but the issue is I can't seem to figure out how to position the backgrounds so that they don't just break up and repeat the same image. I've tried just about everything I can think of to fix the issue, but can't seem to find that middle ground. Any advice would be amazing.

```js
(function(){

  var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax"),
      speed = 0.5;

  window.onscroll = function(){
    [].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(el,i){

      var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
          elBackgrounPos = "0 " + (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";
      
      el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;

    });
  };

})();
```

```css
.empty_canvas_content {
box-shadow:none !important;
}
section.module:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.module h2 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
section.module p {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
section.module p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.module.content {
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color:#fff;
 font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', sans-serif;
 color: #000;
 font-size:12px;
 letter-spacing:0px;
}
section.module.parallax {
  padding: 240px 0;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
section.module.parallax h1 {
  color: #1e1e1e;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* These are the mobile images, push graphic to the left */
section.module.parallax-1 {
  background-image: url("http://s3.postimg.org/3oyk0ti1v/untitled4.jpg");
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:left;
}
section.module.parallax-2 {
  background-image: url("http://s15.postimg.org/keyjegc6z/story2_mobile.jpg");
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:left;
}
section.module.parallax-3 {
  background-image: url("http://s3.postimg.org/5v3hkow6r/pattern3.png");
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:left;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  section.module h2 {
    font-size: 42px;
  }
  section.module p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  section.module.parallax {
    padding: 300px 0;
  }
  
  section.module.parallax-1 {
 background-image: url("http://s10.postimg.org/5p42tdi09/Untitled_3_copy.jpg");
  }
  section.module.parallax-2 {
 background-image: url("http://s15.postimg.org/9e3e9fjy3/story2_desktop.jpg");
  }
  section.module.parallax-3 {
 background-image: url("http://s10.postimg.org/5p42tdi09/Untitled_3_copy.jpg");
  }
  
  section.module.parallax h1 {
    font-size: 96px;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 960px) {
  section.module.parallax h1 {
    font-size: 160px;
  }
  section.module.parallax-1 {
 background-image: url("http://s10.postimg.org/5p42tdi09/Untitled_3_copy.jpg");
  }
  section.module.parallax-2 {
 background-image: url("http://s15.postimg.org/9e3e9fjy3/story2_desktop.jpg");
  }
  section.module.parallax-3 {
 background-image: url("http://s10.postimg.org/5p42tdi09/Untitled_3_copy.jpg");
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="deleteme" style="max-width:1140px; margin: 0 auto;">
<p><section class="module parallax parallax-1">
<div class="holditin">
<center><img src="http://s22.postimg.org/k71wcjnm9/logo.png" width="90%"></center>
</div>
</section>
<section class="module content">
<div class="holditin">
<h2><center>Venture in Style Dream Road Trip Giveaway!</center></h2>
<center><p>Have you ever dreamed of going on the road trip of a lifetime? Maybe it's renting an RV and exploring Route 66? Or driving through the mountains on the Blue Ridge Parkway? Whatever it is, we want to hear about it.</p></center>
</div>
</section>        <section class="module parallax parallax-2">
<div class="holditin">
<h1>Shape</h1>
</div>
</section>        <section class="module content">
<div class="holditin">
<h2><center>We're awarding one lucky winner $5,000 to take it!</center></h2>
<center><p>Tell us in a video that is between 30 seconds and 2 minutes long what your dream road trip is! Upload it below or post it to your Instagram page using <strong>#ventureinstyle</strong> to be entered for a chance to win.</p></center>
</div>
</section>        <section class="module parallax parallax-3">
<div class="holditin">
<h1>Colour</h1>
</div>
</section>        <section class="module content">
<div class="holditin">
<h2><center><font style="letter-spacing:2px;">BE CREATIVE!</font></center></h2>
<center><p>Entries will be judged on creativity and lenght, so make sure your video stands out and meets the required length (:30-2:00).</p></center>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common side of a ***parallax effect***. Since the positioning of the image changes at every scroll the image will cut at some point. Their are some solutions of it and some key ideas to acknowledge :-

1. **Using repeated backgrounds** - By using repeated backgrounds, you can avoid the cutting off backgrounds. Just use a repeated image that seems like their is no edges on the image. This idea is widely used for parallax backgrounds because it provides seamless background effect.
2. **Increase Image Size** - This is also a fix for a parallax background, what you have to do is increase the size of the background. We mainly use `background-size:cover;` for it but for covering the parallax area, you can use `background-size:150% auto;` for portrait(width < height) type image or  use `background-size: auto 150%;` for landscape(width > height) type image. Percentage must be greater than 100% so that it will cover whole parallax area on any screen.

Second point varies from size/resolution/screen size of image.

Thank You.